# Load image from internet url, some are rotated 90 degrees

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

How to recognize the image load from url is rotated?

I have a list of images which are from the url, and some of the loaded images are 90 degrees rotated compared to the original image.

Comment: If they are JPEGs, look for the EXIF `Orientation` header. Stock Android code, like `BitmapFactory`, ignores this, though some image-loading libraries might pay attention to that header (Picasso?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have it. This will re-orientate your image if it is in landscape mode :

```
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();

if (width > height){
    rotatedBitmap = rotate(bitmap,-90)
}


private Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bm, int rotation) {
    if (rotation != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bmOut;
    }
    return bm;
}
```